# Magento 2.2 CMS Blocks/Pages modified date not updating

Tags: database, magento2.2, sorting

The blocks and pages which were created before upgrading to Magento 2.2.1 do not update the "Modified" date in the admin. The contents are updated, but it appears only the date modified is not changed.

Its sounds silly, but i like to sort my modified date for pages and blocks and this has made it so that is no longer a possibility.

I have tried reindexing, update, compile, deploy many, many times without effect.

It also seem to be affecting products "updated at" settings as well. I am guessing this is SQL related, but have no idea where to begin to address this issue.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue has been fixed in Magento 2.3, see [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/12636/commits/22f454dd020719686c558a36d67df6dc13506c3f)

In case you do not want to upgrade to Magento 2.3, you can adapt the changes made to your needs.

Cheers

Comment: Yes it did fix it. You have to edit and then save and it updates with the new date - thank you!